# VSTS API List Iterations (current timeframe) not working in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501737/create-bug-in-a-different-project-when-build-fails) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710446/vsts-api-create-bug-in-current-iteration) SO question for the back story. In short, I am trying to create a bug in a VSTS project using powershell in the *current* iteration.

Following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/work/iterations/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1), if I visit this URL in Chrome (substituted with right values of course) I get the right answer. i.e. the returned list's count is 1 and there is only 1 iteration json serialized object in the the array with the right (current) iteration.

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?$timeframe={$timeframe}&api-version=4.1
```

However, if I use powershell to query the same, I get ALL iterations and not just the current one.

```
$getCurrentIterationAPIURL = "https://account.visualstudio.com/project%20name/team/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?$timeframe=current&api-version=4.1"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $creatorUser,$createrToken)))

$getCurrentIterationResult=Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $getCurrentIterationAPIURL -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Is this a bug on the API side (different behavior based on UserAgent, I tried to specify a UserAgent with Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36, but didn't work) or what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this url instead:

```
$getCurrentIterationAPIURL = "https://account.visualstudio.com/project%20name/team/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?`$timeframe=current&api-version=4.1"
```

Replace `$` to `$