# VSTS API : create bug in current iteration

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am able to successfully create a bug in VSTS using REST API via powershell. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501737/create-bug-in-a-different-project-when-build-fails) question for some back story.

But how do I specify it to create the bug in the *current* iteration ? Do I have to find out what is the current iteration prior to providing the path ? Is there no way to just directly create it in the current iteration ?

Please note that this question is about Create Work Item API, whereas the question mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710424/vsts-api-list-iterations-current-timeframe-not-working-in-powershell) is about the Iteration API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS API List Iterations (current timeframe) not working in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710424/vsts-api-list-iterations-current-timeframe-not-working-in-powershell)

Comment: Actually those are two different questions. The other question is asking about the List Iterations API whereas this one is asking about the Create Work Item API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t such feature in VSTS build, the workaround is that you can update the related work item through web hook.

1. Build a api project (e.g. ASP.NET web api) to update work item per to build id (Get build’s work item through [Get Build Work Items Refs rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=vsts-rest-4.1))
2. Create a web hooks with build completed event, set Failed status in Filters
3. Specify that url of your API app.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way of directly creating a bug in current iteration ? I am able to create a bug via a powershell script but it assigns to default iteration and not current.

Comment: Yes, but you can change the default iteration to @CurrentIteration (`https://xxx.visualstudio.com/{team project}/{team}/_admin/_work?_a=iterations#`), otherwise, you can do it through web hook.

Comment: Can you point me to the User Voice so I can request for this feature ?

Comment: FYI for other. You have to use the List Iterations API supplying timeframe as "current" to find the path of the current iteration and then use it in the create work item API.

Comment: @dparkar You can submit the user voice here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/

Comment: thanks posted : https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34496218-create-work-item-in-current-iteration-using-rest-a